# HttpActionContext.Request does not have CreateResponse Meth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.Net Web API to handle Basic Auth. When overriding HandleUnauthorizedRequest I find that the HttpActionContext.Request doesn't have a CreateResponse method.

The project is MVC 4 targetting .net 4.5. I updated Web API to version 2 using nuget.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace BasicAuth.Security
{
    public class BasicAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return;
            }

            var authHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (authHeader != null)
            {
                if (authHeader.Scheme.Equals("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authHeader.Parameter))
                {
                    var credentials = GetCredentials(authHeader);

                    //Handle authentication

                    return;
                }
            }

          HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }

        private string[] GetCredentials(AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader)
        {
            var raw = authHeader.Parameter;
            var encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
            var credentials = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(raw));

            return credentials.Split(':');
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request. //No CreateResponse Method ?
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure it must be a missing or incorrect reference somewhere, it is rather confusing though. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[`CreateResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969014%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is an extension method defined in the `System.Net.Http` namespace. So make sure you've brought it into scope by adding the correct `using` directive:

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

Comment: Request.CreateResponse() belongs to HttpRequestMessageExtensions living in the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Answer (score 3):

Piggy backing on this post

In a project after some merging and upgrading to latest .net 4.6 we had a related error and this was one of the first posts found.

Symptom: "No overload for method 'Request.CreateResponse()' takes 0 arguments".

Problem: System.Net.Http.Formating was missing in references causing the error

Solution: Request.CreateResponse() belongs to HttpRequestMessageExtensions living in the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client, restore nuget packages and if that does not help remove WebApi.Client (and dependencies) from the project, add it back and the reference to System.Net.Http.Formating will be added again.

(alternative solution: add reference > browse > go to "[solution folder]packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45" and select "System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll"